# Variable changes type when passed in argument?

Tags: python, protocols, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

I am patching a tool that works on the NTLM network protocol, I have a structure object where I index a string and pass to a function, inside the scope of the function the variable changes from a `<type 'str'>` to `<type 'instance'>`.

function call:

```
# type(self.challengeMessage['challenge']) == <type 'str'>
self.ParseHTTPHash(self.challengeMessage['challenge'])
```

inside function:

```
def ParseHTTPHash(challenge):
    # type(challenge) == <type 'instance'>
    challenge.encode("hex") # causes exception due to being instance type and not string
```

challengeMessage object:

```
class NTLMAuthChallenge(Structure):

    structure = (
        ('','"NTLMSSP\x00'),
        ('message_type','<L=2'),
        ('domain_len','<H-domain_name'),
        ('domain_max_len','<H-domain_name'),
        ('domain_offset','<L=40'),
        ('flags','<L=0'),
        ('challenge','8s'),
        ('reserved','8s=""'),
        ('TargetInfoFields_len','<H-TargetInfoFields'),
        ('TargetInfoFields_max_len','<H-TargetInfoFields'),
        ('TargetInfoFields_offset','<L'),
        ('VersionLen','_-Version','self.checkVersion(self["flags"])'), 
        ('Version',':'),
        ('domain_name',':'),
        ('TargetInfoFields',':'))

    @staticmethod
    def checkVersion(flags):
        if flags is not None:
           if flags & NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION == 0:
              return 0
        return 8

    def getData(self):
        if self['TargetInfoFields'] is not None and type(self['TargetInfoFields']) is not bytes:
            raw_av_fields = self['TargetInfoFields'].getData()
            self['TargetInfoFields'] = raw_av_fields
        return Structure.getData(self)

    def fromString(self,data):
        Structure.fromString(self,data)
        self['domain_name'] = data[self['domain_offset']:][:self['domain_len']]
        self['TargetInfoFields'] = data[self['TargetInfoFields_offset']:][:self['TargetInfoFields_len']]
        return self
```

the weird thing is if I pass `self` into `ParseHTTPHasH(self)` and reference it inside the function `self.challengeMessage['challenge']` it doesn't change type to instance. What is going on here?

(Edit:)

Apologizes for the vagueness of the original post its hard to show context with this large file

General Layout Context:

```
class HTTPRelayServer(Thread):
        ...
        # Parse NTLMv1/v2 hash with challengeMessage & token * custom *
        # check out responder ParseSMBHash to implement for smbrelayserver.py
        # replace impacket/impacket/examples/ntlmrelayx/servers/httprelayserver.py
        def ParseHTTPHash(self,client,data):
            LMhashLen    = struct.unpack('<H',data[12:14])[0]
            LMhashOffset = struct.unpack('<H',data[16:18])[0]
            LMHash       = data[LMhashOffset:LMhashOffset+LMhashLen].encode("hex").upper()

            NthashLen    = struct.unpack('<H',data[20:22])[0]
            NthashOffset = struct.unpack('<H',data[24:26])[0]
            NTHash       = data[NthashOffset:NthashOffset+NthashLen].encode("hex").upper()

            UserLen      = struct.unpack('<H',data[36:38])[0]
            UserOffset   = struct.unpack('<H',data[40:42])[0]
            User         = data[UserOffset:UserOffset+UserLen].replace('\x00','')

            # parameter reference
*---------> NumChal = self.challengeMessage['challenge'].encode("hex")

            if NthashLen == 24:
                HostNameLen     = struct.unpack('<H',data[46:48])[0]
                HostNameOffset  = struct.unpack('<H',data[48:50])[0]
                HostName        = data[HostNameOffset:HostNameOffset+HostNameLen].replace('\x00','')
                WriteHash       = '%s::%s:%s:%s:%s' % (User, HostName, LMHash, NTHash, NumChal)

            if NthashLen > 24:
                NthashLen      = 64
                DomainLen      = struct.unpack('<H',data[28:30])[0]
                DomainOffset   = struct.unpack('<H',data[32:34])[0]
                Domain         = data[DomainOffset:DomainOffset+DomainLen].replace('\x00','')
                HostNameLen    = struct.unpack('<H',data[44:46])[0]
                HostNameOffset = struct.unpack('<H',data[48:50])[0]
                HostName       = data[HostNameOffset:HostNameOffset+HostNameLen].replace('\x00','')
                WriteHash      = '%s::%s:%s:%s:%s' % (User, Domain, NumChal, NTHash[:32], NTHash[32:])
            return WriteHash

        def do_PROPFIND(self):
            proxy = False
            if (".jpg" in self.path) or (".JPG" in self.path):
                content = """<?xml version="1.0"?><D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:"><D:response><D:href>http://webdavrelay/file/image.JPG/</D:href><D:propstat><D:prop><D:creationdate>2016-11-12T22:00:22Z</D:creationdate><D:displayname>image.JPG</D:displayname><D:getcontentlength>4456</D:getcontentlength><D:getcontenttype>image/jpeg</D:getcontenttype><D:getetag>4ebabfcee4364434dacb043986abfffe</D:getetag><D:getlastmodified>Mon, 20 Mar 2017 00:00:22 GMT</D:getlastmodified><D:resourcetype></D:resourcetype><D:supportedlock></D:supportedlock><D:ishidden>0</D:ishidden></D:prop><D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status></D:propstat></D:response></D:multistatus>"""
            else:
                content = """<?xml version="1.0"?><D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:"><D:response><D:href>http://webdavrelay/file/</D:href><D:propstat><D:prop><D:creationdate>2016-11-12T22:00:22Z</D:creationdate><D:displayname>a</D:displayname><D:getcontentlength></D:getcontentlength><D:getcontenttype></D:getcontenttype><D:getetag></D:getetag><D:getlastmodified>Mon, 20 Mar 2017 00:00:22 GMT</D:getlastmodified><D:resourcetype><D:collection></D:collection></D:resourcetype><D:supportedlock></D:supportedlock><D:ishidden>0</D:ishidden></D:prop><D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status></D:propstat></D:response></D:multistatus>"""

            messageType = 0
            if self.headers.getheader('Authorization') is None:
                self.do_AUTHHEAD(message='NTLM')
                pass
            else:
                typeX = self.headers.getheader('Authorization')
                try:
                    _, blob = typeX.split('NTLM')
                    token = base64.b64decode(blob.strip())
                except:
                    self.do_AUTHHEAD()
                messageType = struct.unpack('<L', token[len('NTLMSSP\x00'):len('NTLMSSP\x00') + 4])[0]

            if messageType == 1:
                if not self.do_ntlm_negotiate(token, proxy=proxy):
                    LOG.info("do negotiate failed, sending redirect")
                    self.do_REDIRECT()
            elif messageType == 3:
                authenticateMessage = ntlm.NTLMAuthChallengeResponse()
                authenticateMessage.fromString(token)
                if authenticateMessage['flags'] & ntlm.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE:
                    LOG.info("Authenticating against %s://%s as %s\\%s SUCCEED" % (
                        self.target.scheme, self.target.netloc, authenticateMessage['domain_name'].decode('utf-16le'),
                        authenticateMessage['user_name'].decode('utf-16le')))
                else:
                    LOG.info("Authenticating against %s://%s as %s\\%s SUCCEED" % (
                        self.target.scheme, self.target.netloc, authenticateMessage['domain_name'].decode('ascii'),
                        authenticateMessage['user_name'].decode('ascii')))
                self.do_ntlm_auth(token, authenticateMessage)
                self.do_attack()

                # Function call
*------------>  print(self.ParseHTTPHash(self,str(token)))

                self.send_response(207, "Multi-Status")
                self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/xml')
                self.send_header('Content-Length', str(len(content)))
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(content)
                return
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ParseHTTPHash(challenge):
```

If this is a free function (defined outside class), you shouldn't call it `self.ParseHTTPHash(value)`, but simply `ParseHTTPHash(value)`. If it's not `@staticmethod` and it's inside the class - add `self` as first parameter.

Comment: That was my original solve for this problem but `self.ParseHTTPHash(self)` looked weird, like I was programming something wrong. Is this normal?

Comment: No. It's not. Could you show me where is the function call, and where is the ParseHTTPHash function defined?

Comment: ParseHTTPHash is defined in a HTTPServer class and the function call is in another function of HTTPRelayServer, it may be a little hard to show as the file is huge but I added the general layout as an edit to thist post

Answer (score 0):

I guess ParseHTTPHash is a method inside your class. If so please pass self as first parameter.

```
 def ParseHTTPHash(self,challenge)
```

Answer (score 0):

All normal instance methods of a class (not `@staticmethod` or whatever) take a first parameter, which is the object on which they've been invoked.

So, when you call

```
obj.foo(param)
```

on an object `obj` of class `C`, it translates to roughly

```
C.foo(obj, param)
```

which is usually implemented as

```
class C:
    def foo(self, param):
        pass # whatever
```

Otherwise the instance method wouldn't know which instance of class `C` it was supposed to be working on.

So, if `ParseHTTPHash` is an instance method, you *should* call it as `self.ParseHTTPHash(param)`, but you declared it wrong.

If `ParseHTTPHash` is *not* an instance method, you should *not* call it as `self.ParseHTTPHash(param)` in the first place, because that syntax is specifically for instance methods.

The only way to know which case applies is for you to show the definition of `ParseHTTPHash` as @RafalS asked.